# glGetString(GL_VERSION) returns NULL while OpenGL was initialized

Tags: opengl, windows

I'm trying to make *.obj loader. When I thought that everything is solved I can't init GLEW to work with my loader.

The thing is that my application initialization looks like this:

```
int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance,
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                    int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    MSG msg;
    HWND hWnd;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Projekt";

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(  NULL,
                            L"Projekt",
                            L"Symulator lodzi",
                            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                            100, 50,
                            SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                            NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (!hWnd)
        return 0;

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow); //wyswietlanie okna

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (err != GLEW_OK)
    {
        const GLubyte* error = glGetString(GL_VERSION);
        const GLubyte* error2 = glewGetErrorString(err);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (TRUE)
    {
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            break;
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

After CreateWindowEx is called it all goes to WM_CREATE message in WndProc function, which looks like this:

```
case WM_CREATE:
        {
            SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 1000, (TIMERPROC)NULL);
            if (oGL == NULL)
                oGL = new OpenGL(hWnd);

            hDC = GetDC(hWnd);
        } break;
```

And oGL constructor code is here:

```
OpenGL::OpenGL(HWND hWnd)
{
    static PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = {
                                        sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
                                        1,
                                        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,
                                        PFD_TYPE_RGBA,              
                                        32,                           
                                        0, 0, 0,
                                        0, 0, 0,                      
                                        0, 0,                         
                                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                
                                        32,                           
                                        0,                             
                                        0,                             
                                        PFD_MAIN_PLANE,                 
                                        0,                             
                                        0,                             
                                        0,                              
                                        0                               
                                        };

    int pixelFormatID;
    HDC hDC;

    hDC = GetDC(hWnd);

    pixelFormatID = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd);
    SetPixelFormat(hDC, pixelFormatID, &pfd);

    hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC);
    wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
}
```

So I think that OpenGL is initialized properly, but then I'm receiving those erros:

[image: errors message screenshot]

I don't understand why application thinks that OpenGL wasn't initialized yet, when it was (I've been debuging it step by step and for sure first was created window and then oGL object).

Comment: What makes you think your message handler has been called before your code reached your message pump?

Comment: I've been tracking code in debug mode and after reaching CreateWindowsEx next lines called were in WM_CREATE message. Even when I've put breakpoint in WM_CREATE and on getting error lines the first one, that code stoped on., was WM_CREATE

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a OpenGL context at the time of trying to initialize GLEW. The WM_CREATE message is processed only after entering the message loop, through DispatchMessage. Before processing WM_CREATE, your program doesn't have a context.

Just create the OpenGL context after create window, and not in WM_CREATE. Much easier and avoids that ordering issue.

Comment: Ok I'll check that. I was 100% sure that WM_CREATE was called after CreateWindowsEx, because VS studio showed this way.

Comment: When I'm removing creating context from WM_CREATE I'm getting errors that some variables weren't initialized (they come from WndProc function after CreateWindowsEx call). So I have to create my OpenGL context in WM_CREATE and when I'm trying to create it againt just before glewInit() it is already created.

Comment: @KamilPrzybyo: variables being uninitialized is not an error as long as you don't try to read from them. Either way, plain Win32 API programs that create OpenGL contexts in WM_CREATE are a bit unusual. It's kind of common for MFC based programs, though. Either way, you should do GLEW initialization together with context creation. Or rather, you actually have to create `glewInit` after each `wglMakeCurrent` invocation; that's because in Windows extension entry points actually may differ between contexts. You seem to try wrapping GL in classes (tough!); you could wrap the function pointers then.

Comment: That answer really helped me ! I've just moved initializating glew to my OpenGL class constructor, right after wglMakeCurrent and everything now works fine. I've been trying to call glewInit right after creating OpenGL class object and it didn't work. It had to be after wglMakeCurrent. Thank you for your help